# Is there a difference between these two expressions in python

Tags: python

So, basically I just started learning python and I can't find something that proves if these two instructions do the same thing or not
I have two lists and I want to copy one into another, the thing is that I do not understood if this instruction is right
`newList = [x[:] for x in List]`
because `newList = List` does the same thing 
Is there a difference between these two instructions?
Thanks!

Comment: essentially same

Comment: It does a two level deep copy. Yours does not.

Comment: They don't do the same thing. The second creates an alias (two references to only one object), the first a copy.

Comment: newList = List.copy() is the same as the first instruction ?

Comment: No. The copy method just makes a shallow copy. Google deep vs.   shallow copy in Python. For lists of lists they are not the same.

Comment: Please follow Python style conventions, and don’t name a variable `list'.

Comment: No they aren't the same thing **at all**

Answer (score -2):

In the first cursory look they look essentially same but there could be a difference if the List is not a list of lists [as is immediately understood by its name] ..if List is actually a tuple of tuples (supposing a naming mistake .. :-)) or something else. In such a case you are creating a list of tuples (by the first command) from what was initially something else. Other such possibilities also exist. So please see the print and type of NewList and List carefully. A subtle difference and they are not same.

**You might be actually doing a type conversion if you are following the first command.**

Consider the code below.

```py
List = tuple( (x,x+1) for x in range(10))
newList = [x[:] for x in List]
```

The output of print and type reveal the difference instantly.

```py
print(List)
print(newList)
type(List)
type(newList)
```

respective Outputs

```py
((0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8), (8, 9), (9, 10))
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8), (8, 9), (9, 10)]
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'list'>
```

Comment: This ignores the most serious difference. The whole bit about types seems mostly irrelevant. "there could be a difference if the List is not a list of lists" The two are different regardless of that fact.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to mention that it was a 2 dimensional array, so the first instruction copies element by element in a new list and the second one just references the first one. Thanks!

Comment: Yes you are right. I am really sorry about the post. I should have logged off by now. They are not same. They are two different instructions. Sorry again. Tome to take break from SO for some days. I will probably leave my post as it is as an example how not to post things. Bad.

Comment: @Amit _I will probably leave my post as it is as an example how not to post things._ What a bad idea, why would you do that?

Comment: @Amit, it's better to delete this. FYI: you lose 2 points per downvote. If you remove this post, you will receive those points back.

Comment: As per this link (https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), none of the six bulleted criteria apply in **my opinion**. Apart from this (a) Some members have got upvotes as comments. They have earned it. (b) During an experiment a positive result and negative result both are important. Both guide community (read the "would be posters") on how to conduct future experiments. These two benefits to others outweigh few points I might get back. This is a wrong answer sure but if the **post+comments, combined, are really "such a *useless* post in long run"** it can be marked for deletion. Best,